# JSDT extension point reference

Tags: eclipse-plugin, jsdt

I'd like to develop some extensions to the jsdt plugin of eclipse. However i can't seem to find a detailed documentation of the extension points available in jsdt. (Something like the eclipse help provides for the eclipse core extension points).

Where can i find detailed documentation on that topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find JSDT extension documentation here - [JSDT Help](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/nav/24_4), you may also want to browse the Eclipse wiki.